# How to prevent p:poll resetting interval after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using `<p:poll>` tag to invoke a dialog box after each 3 minutes. Its working fine if I remain in same page. But if i traverse to another page of application, the interval property of `p:poll` tag get reset e.i if I stay for 1 min in page1 then move to page2 I suppose to get activate dialog box in next 2 min but again it take 3 min to show dialog box.

**usefull info:**

1. my CDI bean is in @SessionScoped
2. `<p:poll>` tag place in masterLayout.xhtml

Thakns in advance

Comment: I'm avoiding to use java script setInterval() method. want some solution java side or by using primefaces API

Comment: Simplest solution: do partial page updates. Not full page updates if this is such an important requirement. Better solution: use `p:push` so the server can decide when to update.

Comment: I bind a instance variable from my CDI bean which is in session scoped with `interval` property. Its working fine

Comment: Please post a useful 'answer' for others to learn